# Javascript toggle list items with button ID change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I want to create a navbar what is appear by floating down from the top after button click. When I press the button, it start the function what is float it down, and change the button's id, so the next click will be another function.

The first click is working, the second not.

```
<nav>
        <div class="toggle">
            <input type="image" src="img/menu-toggle.png" id="circleMenuBtnDown">
        </div>
        <ul id="dropDownMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <script>
            function floatDown(ele) {
                ele.animate({ 'top': '+=70px' }, 200, function () {
                    var nxt = ele.next();
                    if (nxt.length)
                        floatDown(nxt);
                });
            }
            function floatUp(ele) {
                ele.animate({ 'top': '-=70px' }, 200, function () {
                    var nxt = ele.next();
                    if (nxt.length)
                        floatUp(nxt);
                });
            }

            $("#circleMenuBtnDown").click(function () {
                $("#circleMenuBtnDown").eq(0).attr('id', 'circleMenuBtnUp');
                floatDown($('#dropDownMenu li').eq(0));

            });

            $("#circleMenuBtnUp").click(function () {
                $("#circleMenuBtnUp").eq(0).attr('id', 'circleMenuBtnDown');
                floatUp($('#dropDownMenu li').eq(0));
            });
    </script>
```

The second click don't change the button's id, and keep start the function floatDown

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `click` listener to the `circleMenuBtnUp` within the `floatDownListener` and unbind the `click` listener of `circleMenuBtnDown`.

```js
function floatDown(ele) {
  ele.animate({
    'top': '+=70px'
  }, 200, function() {
    var nxt = ele.next();
    if (nxt.length)
      floatDown(nxt);
  });
}

function floatUp(ele) {
  ele.animate({
    'top': '+=70px'
  }, 200, function() {
    var nxt = ele.next();
    if (nxt.length)
      floatUp(nxt);
  });
}

function floatUpListener() {
  $("#circleMenuBtnUp").eq(0).attr('id', 'circleMenuBtnDown');
  floatUp($('#dropDownMenu li').eq(0));
  $("#circleMenuBtnUp").unbind(floatUpListener, false);
  $("#circleMenuBtnDown").bind('click', floatDownListener);
}

function floatDownListener() {
  $("#circleMenuBtnDown").eq(0).attr('id', 'circleMenuBtnUp');
  floatDown($('#dropDownMenu li').eq(0));
  $('#circleMenuBtnUp').unbind('click', false);
  $("#circleMenuBtnUp").bind('click', floatUpListener);
}

$('#circleMenuBtnDown').click(floatDownListener)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="toggle">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" src="img/menu-toggle.png" id="circleMenuBtnDown">
  </div>
  <ul id="dropDownMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is something wrong with it. It's loop both of the functions, and add another after every click.